# HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type when doing POST request on Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, content-type

I am trying to send a post request on a simple Spring MVC web app and use `RequestBody` in my controller to convert the JSON into a Java Object but for whatever reason, I keep getting `HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type`. I have spent a lot of time trying to find a solution to this but nothing seems to be working.

The get method in my Controller seems to be working fine. This is my original code

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class MyControllerAgain {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public void handleJson(@RequestBody Contact c) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json")
    public void handleGet() {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
```

This is my `Contact`

```
public class Contact {

    int id;

    public String name;

    public int number;

    public Contact(){}

    // Getters and setters
}
```

I am sending a request with Postman and this is what it looks like

```
POST /users HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 511c9e03-4178-380d-58f8-db24a3245b9e

{
    "id":1,
    "name":"something",
    "number":1
}
```

I have also tried including Jackson dependencies in my `pom.xml` .
I have tried altering consume value in `@RequestMapping` annotation and I have tried all combinations of headers accept and Content type in my request.

Also, If I use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`, then everything works fine except all the fields in `Contact` class are null.

Here is the github link - https://github.com/Sanil2108/test_springmvc

Comment: Contact class has getter setter ?

Comment: @drowny added getters and setters, no difference

Comment: Have you tried @RestController, instead of @Controller?

Comment: @EvrisTzam Yes, I have tried it.

Comment: Does the GET request work?

Comment: @EvrisTzam yes the get request works fine.

Comment: It seems something is really misconfigured in your project. Is this a new project? If yes I suggest to use SpringBoot. It configures everything for common usecases. That controller works perfectly in a brand new Spring Boot project without any extra configuration.

Comment: Okay, I will look into Spring Boot. It is a new project.

Comment: @Selindek I tried it with Spring boot and everything worked perfectly. Thanks for the advice! I wish I understood why it didn't work before though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried everything but couldn't it to work. Maybe I was making a silly mistake somewhere or there was something seriously wrong with my configuration. Anyway, I tried to make it work with Spring boot and it worked fine. For anyone who is interested, Here is the github link - https://github.com/Sanil2108/spring_hibernate/tree/master/spring_boot1

Also, thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like that the jpa anotations are messing up the json deserialization.

The error returned from the spring server could be misleading.
Try using plain object with setters and getters and see if this changes anything.
You should search for some exceptions in the logs.

Comment: Removed JPA annotations and still I am getting the same problem. There are no server logs after DispatcherServlet inititalization.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mapping to the `handleGet` method, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json")
public void handleGet() {
    System.out.println("a");
}
```

--UPDATE--

Remove the `consumes = "application/json"` part from you GET call. It sees that **both** requests that listen to "/users" can consume json data, but one is a GET and the other one is a POST.

--2nd UPDATE--
This will definitely work. Tested.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class ContactController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
        public void handleJson(@RequestBody Contact c) 
        {
           System.out.println(c);
        }
}
```

Comment: The post method is the one that is not working actually. I did, however, try your solution but the post method is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestMapping` annotation not only has the `consumes` but also `produces`.

But to avoid all these settings for HTTP REST, you can use `RestController` annotation and `GetMapping`, `PostMapping` etc..

You can find an example in my [github](https://github.com/dehasi/scc_gp/blob/master/src/main/java/me/dehasi/contracts/demo/controller/UserController.java)